# How to access stdClass element in php ?

Tags: php

I query db and I have an array. How can I access stdClass object ? And I want also serializedName property like in java serializedName. So, The fields which query from db must be assign with my custom object class fields.How can I use this?

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [receipt_id] => 1
                [defect] => asd
                [tec_report] => sad
                [doc_number] => asd
                [warrant] => 12
                [warrant_start] => 2016-01-05
                [warrant_end] => 2016-01-29
                [repair_time] => 3
                [receipt_date] => 2016-01-05
                [delivery_date] => 
                [service_type_id] => 0
                [service_price] => 0
                [part_price] => 0
                [pay_type] => 
                [labour] => 0
                [summary] => 0
                [technician_id] => 
                [customer_id] => 0
                [device_id] => 0
                [seri_number] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [receipt_id] => 2
                [defect] => asdsad
                [tec_report] => asds
                [doc_number] => 
                [warrant] => 
                [warrant_start] => 
                [warrant_end] => 
                [repair_time] => 
                [receipt_date] => 2016-01-05
                [delivery_date] => 
                [service_type_id] => 1
                [service_price] => 12
                [part_price] => 12
                [pay_type] => 
                [labour] => 12
                [summary] => 12
                [technician_id] => 
                [customer_id] => 21
                [device_id] => 12
                [seri_number] => 
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for one by one
 `echo $array[0]->receipt_id`;

Comment: Thank you guys. I forgot php is elastic :) .

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
foreach($yourArray as $val){
echo $val->receipt_id;
echo "<br/>".$val->defect;
}
```